# Saving and using a cookie with CDI

Tags: jsf, cookies, javabeans, cdi

I am trying to save a Cookie upon user request, and to later use that cookie to fill in a text field.  I am using Java CDI and a login bean.  I am new to all three. For online resources all I can find is

```
@Inject @CookieParam
private String username;
```

and

```
@Inject @CookieParam("username")
private Instance<String> usernameResolver;
...
String username = usernameResolver.get();
```

For the first one the error message says `" Unsatisfied dependencies for type [String] with qualifiers [@Default]"`

For the second one the only error I get says `"Failed to start context"`

How should I fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: "login bean"? A bean? What kind of class is that? Who's managing that class? What web framework are you actually using? The `@CookieParam` is, as its package name hints, specific to JAX-RS, the Java EE's RESTful framework, and obviously won't work on classes managed by another Java EE framework such as JSF, Servlet, etc.

Comment: Oh ok, ya the framework is JSF. I wouldn't have known that they aren't compatible. I can't find any resources on that though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [`@CookieParam` package name](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/CookieParam.html) hints, this is specific to JAX-RS, Java EE's other framefork for RESTful web services. This would only work in a JAX-RS managed resource as annotated by `@Path`. This won't work in a JSF or CDI managed bean as annotated by `@ManagedBean` or `@Named`.

If you're using JSF's `@ManagedBean` to manage the bean, then it's available by EL-evaluating `#{cookie.username}` as `@ManagedProperty`.

```
@ManagedBean
public class Bean {

    @ManagedProperty("#{cookie.username}")
    private String username;

    // ...
}
```

If you're using CDI's `@Named` to manage the bean, then you've resort to either a custom annotation, or grabbing it as [`Cookie`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html) from the current `FacesContext`. As the former is not trivial (but actually a nice idea for [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org/) though), I'll show only the latter:

```
@Named
public class Bean {

    private String username;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Cookie cookie = (Cookie) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestCookieMap().get("username");

        if (cookie != null) {
            username = cookie.getValue();
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then, in order to save it, the only way is using [`ExternalContext#addResponseCookie()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#addResponseCookie%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%29).

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().addResponseCookie("username", username, properties);
```

Don't forget to take into account that a cookie value is very restrictive as to allowed characters. You might want to URL-encode and -decode it upon save and retrieval. JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) offers helper methods which do that implicitly.

```
username = Faces.getRequestCookie("username");
```

```java
Faces.addResponseCookie("username", username, -1);
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, storing something sensitive like "user name" as a cookie is scary. Are you aware that cookies are manipulatable by the enduser? That the person who's visiting your webpage can easily edit a cookie value representing an "user name" to that of someone else?

Comment: Ok that is useful to know.  I will change the name in my code.

Comment: Also for the second block of code did you mean Named instead of ManagedBean?  I am using Named

Comment: This works, I just had to type cast it to be a string.